# How to convert TimeStamp directly into Seconds through Java

Tags: java

With help of JodaTime we can do following conversion

```
     **import org.joda.time.DateTime;**
```

Ex: long timestamp= 12673728936778;

```
     DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp);
     int seconds = dateTime.getSecondOfMinute();
```

Comment: It seems like you found your answer?

Comment: Is than example input incorrect? If not, what exactly does it represent? If it were a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z, the number 12673728936778 would mean a date-time of `2371-08-13T16:15:36.778Z`. I assume this is not the value you intended.

Comment: The Joda-Time framework is now in maintenance-mode. Its leader, Stephen Colebourne, went on to create the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later, as well as the *ThreeTen-Backport* project bringing those classes to Java 6 & 7.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** @BasilBourque's comment makes sense and I suggest implementing this solution instead.

```
long timeStamp = 1613624926599L;

ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeStamp).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
int seconds = dateTime.getSecond();
```

---

You almost got it.

Instead of using `DateTime`, use `LocalDateTime`. Both **JodaTime** and **java.time** have `LocalDateTime` so this solution should work for you.

Here is what I did:

```
long timeStamp = 1613624926599L;

LocalDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeStamp).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
int seconds = dateTime.getSecond();
```

Comment: There is no point to your use of `LocalDateTime` here. You are discarding the valuable time zone information. While your code technically works in this particular case, there is nothing gained by your call to `toLocalDateTime`, and it introduces confusion to anyone reading this code who understands the nature of these classes. Just stick with the `ZonedDateTime` object returned by `atZone`. Like this: `ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeStamp).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) ;` Then ask for the minute is the same manner: `int secondOfMinute = zdt.getSecond() ;` Less code, more info.

Comment: @BasilBourque you're right. I have updated the answer accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you consolidate the two parts, so you have one unified Answer.